# What is the difference for the indexing between x[:] [1] and x [:,1]?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a hard time understanding the difference between these two kinds of indexing.
Let's say I have a nested nested list:

`x = np.array([[[1,2],[5,6]],[[9,7],[12,23]]])`

if I did

`x[:][:][1] and x[:,:,1]`

I would get

```
[[9 7][12 23]] 
[[5 6][12 23]]
```

respectively.

To be honest, I have no clue as to how I would get these results. Could someone explain the steps to me as to how I would get these arrays ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with python's slice syntax. Essentially, `obj[a:b:c]` is syntactic shorthand for `obj.__getitem__(slice(a,b,c))`.

`x[:]` simply returns a 'full slice' of `x` - that is, it returns an exact copy of `x`. Doing `x[:][:][1]` is no different from doing `x[1]`.

Meanwhile, doing `x[:,:,1]` equates to:

```
x.__getitem__((slice(), slice(), 1))
```

that is, *using a 3-tuple as an index*. For an ordinary python `list`, this would fail, but Numpy accepts it gracefully. To see how Numpy does so, let's look a bit closer at this example:

```
>>> x = np.array([[[1,2],[5,6]],[[9,7],[12,23]]])
>>> x[1]
array([[ 9,  7],
       [12, 23]])
>>> x[:,1]
array([[ 5,  6],
       [12, 23]])
>>> x[:,:,1]
array([[ 2,  6],
       [ 7, 23]])
>>> x[:,:,:,1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 3-dimensional, but 4 were indexed
```

We can see a pattern.

When you give a Numpy array a tuple as an index, it maps each element of the tuple to a dimension, and then applies the subsequent elements of the tuple to each of those dimensions. In short:

- `x[1]` just gets the element at index 1 from the first dimension of the array. This is the single element `[[9, 7], [12, 23]]`
- `x[:, 1]` gets the element at index 1 from *each element* in the first dimension of the array. Which is to say, it gets the elements at index 1 from the *second dimension* of the array. This is two elements: `[5, 6]` and `[12, 23]`. Numpy groups them together in a list.
- `x[:, :, 1]` follows the same pattern - it gets the elements at index 1 from the *third dimension* of the array. This time there are four unique elements: `2` and `6` from the first element in the second dimension, and, `7` and `23` from the second element in the second dimension. Numpy groups them by dimension in a nested list.
- `x[:, :, :, 1]` fails, because the array only has three dimensions - there's no way to further subdivide any of the third dimension's elements.